# multiple threading in nested loop in vb

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

I'm new to threading concept in VB .NET and I have two nested for each loops and I want a new thread every time loop executes. What I'm doing here is that I'm calling a function every again and again with different parameters with the help of two nested loops. And what I want is every time I call that function that get executed as a new thread.

Here's my Code -

```
         Dim threadCount As Integer = 1
         Dim theradArray(100) As System.Threading.Thread
         Dim copyProcessID As Integer = 0

         For Each dest_path As String In destList  
           If Directory.Exists(dest_path) Then   




            'copy process

            Dim copyProcessOBJ As copy
            For index = 0 To sourceList.Count - 1
                source = sourceList(index)

                If source.isChecked = True Then

                    copyProcessID += 1
                    If cliRadioButton.Checked Then
                        cmdCopy(source.Path, dest_path)
                    Else

                        ProgressReports.Show()
                        copyProcessOBJ = New copy
                        threadCount += 1
                        theradArray(threadCount) = New _System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf copyProcessOBJ.guiCopy)
                        theradArray(threadCount).Start()
                        copyProcessOBJ.guiCopy(source.Path, dest_path, copyProcessID)

                    End If

                End If
            Next
```

Here I have a class named copy and a sub 'guiCopy' Inside that
I'm making new instance of that obj every time in loop. likewise that I want a new thread.

But I have a problem which says initializes new instance of Thread class.
I'm sorry I know it's my fault that I don't know how to implement it.

Just need Help

Comment: please include the full exception message. Also, what does copy.guiCopy method actually do? How many threads are you starting etc, because im sure this is a poor design, and your problem could be solved in a much simpler way, probably usings tasks or parallel.for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
             Dim threadCount As Integer = 1
             Dim theradArray(100) As System.Threading.Thread
             Dim copyProcessID As Integer = 0
             Dim threads As List(Of System.Threading.Thread) = New List(Of System.Threading.Thread)
             For Each dest_path As String In destList  
               If Directory.Exists(dest_path) Then   
                Dim thr As System.Threading.Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf yourfunction)
                threads.Add(thr)
                threads.LastOrDefault().Start()
                End If
               Next

    Private Sub yourfunction()

                Dim copyProcessOBJ As copy
                For index = 0 To sourceList.Count - 1
                    source = sourceList(index)

                    If source.isChecked = True Then

                        copyProcessID += 1
                        If cliRadioButton.Checked Then
                            cmdCopy(source.Path, dest_path)
                        Else

                            ProgressReports.Show()
                            copyProcessOBJ = New copy
                            threadCount += 1
                            theradArray(threadCount) = New _System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf copyProcessOBJ.guiCopy)
                            theradArray(threadCount).Start()
                            copyProcessOBJ.guiCopy(source.Path, dest_path, copyProcessID)

                        End If
     End If        

    End Sub

   Next
```